# Json remove the last column from table

Tags: json, forms, html-table

I am working with a JSON file that has been generated from code generator. I have been to customize the file to my needs, but unfortunately I am not able to remove the last column from a table.

The code is:

```
{{#subject}}Servicekosten berekening{{/subject}}

<p>Geachte {{sp_name}},<br/>Bedankt voor het invullen van het formulier voor een berekening van uw servicekosten. De details zijn als volgt: </p>
<br/>
<p>Datum: {{date}}</p>
<br/>
<h1>Servicekosten ({{formTitle}})</h1>

<h2>Items</h2>

{{#options}}
    <div class=\"group\">

    <h4>{{title}}</h4>
    <p>{{description}}</p>
    <table border=\"1\">
        <tr>
            <th>Optie</th>
            <th>Selectie</th>
            <th>Prijs</th>
        </tr>
        {{#values}}
            {{#data}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{title}}</td>
                <td>{{value}}</td>
                <td>{{costFormatted}}</td>
            </tr>
            {{/data}}
        {{/values}}
        {{#groupQuantity}}
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Subtotaal: </td>
            <td>{{groupUnitCostFormatted}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Hoeveelheid: </td>
            <td>{{groupQuantity}}</td>
        </tr>
        {{/groupQuantity}}
        {{#groupCost}}
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Totaal: </td>
            <td>{{groupCostFormatted}}</td>
        </tr>
        {{/groupCost}}
    </table>
    </div>

    <hr/>

{{/options}}

<h2>Totale kosten: {{totalCostFormatted}}</h2>
```

It looks like this:

[image: Table]

How can I edit the code to remove the last column, "Prijs"

Comment: I don't know what that is, but it isn't JSON. Also, could you please format it so that it's readable?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing related to a json file. You have to understand how html table works.

the `<th>` is a table header. You have 3 of them for that reason, there is 3 columns. And each `<tr>` is a table row. The `<td>` are the actual cells on each row. If you want to remove the 3rd column in the. You have to remove the 3rd `<td>` and 3rd `<th>`. In each `<tr>` there shouldn't be more than 2 `<td>`.

Read this to understand how it works.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

And then the rest of the template doesn't have to be changed. Only the html part.